# Writing a large file prevents large block DMA allocation

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, arm, dma, sata

I'm working with a board with an ARM based processor running linux (3.0.35). Board has 1GB RAM and is connected to a fast SSD HD, and to a 5MP camera.

My goal is capturing high resolution images and write those directly to disk.

All goes well until I'm trying to save a very long video (over 1GB of data),

After saving a large file, it seems that I'm unable to reload the camera driver - it fails allocating a large enough DMA memory block for streaming (when calling dma_alloc_coherent()).

I narrowed it down to a scenario where Linux boots (when most of the memory is available), I then write random data into a large file (>1GB), and when I try to load the camera driver it fails.

To my question -

When I open a file for writing, write a large amount of data, and close the file, isn't the memory which was used for writing the data to HD supposed to be freed?

I can understand the why the memory becomes fragmented during the HD access, but when the transactions to the HD are completed - why is the memory still so fragmented that I cannot allocate 15MB of contiguous RAM?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> [...] close the file, isn't the memory which was used for writing the data to HD supposed to be freed?

No, it will be **cached**, you can check `/proc/meminfo` for this. Whether the `dma_alloc_coherent()` function uses only free memory is a good question.

Comment: Indeed.  Good odds are that the writes to flash are relatively slow and there aren't 15MB of free pages to pin for DMA.

Comment: Thanks Turbo! But isn't cached memory considered as FREE when it comes to new memory allocations? Also, if I drop the caches, the problem is still there...